# Brasero Disc Burner does not behave. How to address it in command line?

Tags: linux

As you know the Brasero Disc Burner is the default disc burner in some Linux environments.

I used Brasero a few times, each time choosing a different speed at the outset. But no matter which speed I chose, Brasero overrode my choice during the burning process. The speed was increased quite autonomously during the burning process (no interference from me). Then an error message appeared, by which I knew I had lost the DVD.

There is a rumor out there saying that sometimes the GUI environment is responsible for the misbehavior of certain software. In light of this rumor, I am wondering if the Brasero can be used in command line, hoping that speed choice would not be overwritten.

Anyone has any idea how Brasero can be used in command line? How this problem can be addressed otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

It is my personal experience that Brasero is terrible. It has never correctly burned a disc for me.

Try using an alternative software such as K3B

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have found this link useful too:  http://linux.die.net/man/1/brasero

Comment: the most automatic thing one can do with it seems `brasero -p test_project --immediately`.